# Scrapy Spider does not enter parse_item method using SgmlLinkExtractor Rule

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am making a crawler to crawl the website recursively but the problem is the spider does not enter the parse_item method.The name of my spider is example.py. The code is given below:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url


class CrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "example"
    download_delay = 2
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    print allowed_domains
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Arts/"
    ]
    print start_urls
    rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/Arts', )), callback='parse_item',follow=True),
      )

#The spide is not entering into this parse_item

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print "hello parse"
        sel = Selector(response)
        title = sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
        print title
```

Comment: Is the url `http://www.tutorial.com/tutorials/steps` correct? I've opened up it in the web-browser, got redirected to `http://www.tutorial.com/?f`. Besides, on the page there are no links with `/tutorials` in the `href`.

Comment: NO! it is an arbitrary URL, i have mentioned for giving the example.But if i replace it with genuine URL it still didn't work.Although I have one more spider in the same project and the parse_item is working fine there having the same code.

Comment: @rohan I think you are using wrong regex in `allow` .. can give few examples of link which you are trying to scrape ?

Comment: @vipul i have updated the code kindly check it.

Comment: If you want to get about all the links inside `Arts` then you should give the regex in `allow` as `allow=('/Arts/.*')`. This would match everything after `www.dmoz.org/Arts/..` e.g. `www.dmoz.org/Arts/Movies` and so on

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to define and call a function explicitly?
Try this:

```
class CrawlSpider(CrawlSpider):
   name = "example"
   download_delay = 2
   allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
   print allowed_domains
   start_urls = ["http://www.dmoz.org/Arts/"]

   def parse(self, response):
      print "hello parse"
      sel = Selector(response)
      title = sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
      print title
```